# Como configurar CORS no SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, cors

Recentemente resolvi experimentar desenvolver em java com o Spring boot. Não sou muito experiente nessa framework. Tentei fazer uma aplicação completa, com back-end com essa tecnologia e front-end com Vue  usando Axios para realizar requisições.

Fiz o back-end usando postman, mas senti necessidades de realizar requisições no desenvolvimento do front. Tentei realizar a configuração de CORS usando [Esse](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)  e [Esse](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) tutoriais para configuração, mas independente da forma, minhas requisições estão sendo bloqueadas. Cheguei a configurar da seguinte forma:

```java
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
```

Mas mesmo assim minhas requisições continuam sendo bloqueadas por CORS.

Meu Axios está configurado da seguinte forma:

```js
export default axios.create({
    baseURL:"localhost:8081",
    withCredentials:true
})
```

O meu Back-end está rodando na porta 8081, enquanto meu front está na porta 8080. Literalmente não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59938757/4319922. Veja se essa anotação @CrossOrigin ajuda.

Comment: Se não me engano o navegador bloqueia o `allow-origin: *` quando houver a flag `withCredentials`. Basicamente você não pode permitir para todos se houver credenciais na requisição. Pode ser isso, verifique no console do navegador o erro que ocorre